# メタでは無い方の「Markdown や HTML を使用して投稿を書式設定するには？」の一部のリンクが切れている

Tags: バグ, 完了, ヘルプ

[Markdown や HTML を使用して投稿を書式設定するには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

の最初にある「一部のHTML」のURLがホスト名を省略した形であるため、メタではない方のスタック・オーバーフローでは、404 Not Found になってしまいます(メタ内のページであるため、メタでは正常)。ホスト名を含めたURLに変更する必要があります。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

確認したところ、一つ前の編集で省略表記する形にしていたようなので、ホスト名を含めた完全な URL を指定するようリンクを修正しておきました。